# Get the class object of an instance variable in java

Tags: java

I have a class Route which have a instance variable of type stop(different class type). Now I have a function with return type stop. How can I get the route object associated with this stop object

```
public class Route{
   Stop stopInstance;

   public Route(){
       stopInstance = new Stop();
   }
}

//Stop class in another file
public class Stop{   String name;

   public Stop(){
      name = " no name specified yet";
   }
}

//Some function in another class MainClass
class MainClass{
   Stop stop = func();
   //A function with return type Stop
   public Stop func(){
     Route route = new Route();
     return route.getStop();  
//Assume getter and setter functions for route class for stop variable
   }

// now I need to get the route object reference associated with the stop object reference I received from func(). 
}
```

I know it can be solved with an additional field in Stop class of type Route, but is there any other way?

Comment: Can you please show us code ?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking... Put the code, that ll clear up a lot of confusion...

Comment: Child does not have a reference to the parent in *composition*. You can't get it

Comment: In your Stop class, add a avariable with Owner type and set it.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - The OP has reference to instance `B` inside `A`. He has access to `B`'s instance, using that he wants to get `A's` instance

Comment: @TheLostMind `stop.setParent(this)`. It's not child.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Parent and child can still be used with composition :)